# Facing a GPU memory leak in the training of multi-head attention to generate sentences in an autoregressive way

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, time-series, transformer-model

I am working on time series forecasting using GPT-like model. The idea is similar to train a language model that, given the beginning part of a sentence, the model can generate the rest of that sentence.

“I’m hungry, I want a hamburger and a cup of cola.”

Input: I’m hungry

Predict: I want a hamburger and a cup of cola.

An autoregressive language model will generate words step by step.

I’m hungry, I
I’m hungry, I want
I’m hungry, I want a
……
I’m hungry, I want a hamburger and a cup of cola.

That is, the newly generated word will be appended to the end of the previous input sequence to construct the new input sequence. During training, I will calculate the loss on the generated content “I want a hamburger and a cup of cola” and use back-propagation to update model parameters. The generation process can be implemented through a for-loop and a “decoder-only” module.

However, the GPU memory usage always spikes in this for-loop.

Do you have any suggestions to optimize the implementation?

Do you think my implementation is the right way to generate word sequences?

My time series forecasting sequence contains around 100 elements, that is, the for-loop repeat operation 100 times.

Comment: There is no code here, nothing can be said without code.

Answer (score -1):

The implementation of the autoregressive language model for time series forecasting is generally correct, but there are several ways to optimize it to reduce the memory usage and improve the performance. i can suggest us is by using a generator

Instead of using a for-loop to generate the sequence, you can use a generator. Generators are functions that can be paused and resumed, which can be useful for reducing memory usage. You can define a generator function that yields the next element in the sequence, and then use a for-loop to iterate over the generator.